# How do I transform this sinusoid in phasor?

Tags: phasor

[image]

If it is a signal like this i(t)=5*sin(100t-pi/3)A, I know how to transform.
But how do I do this e(t)=2-√(2)*sin(10t+pi/4) ?
I meant I don't know what to do with "2-"

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hint: that's the sum of two signals.

Comment: I don't think you can -- at least not unless you allow \$t\$ in your resulting phasor.

Comment: Consider the sum of two signals 2*sin(0t+pi/2)-√(2)*sin(10t+pi/4) the first term is unvarying i.e. DC

Answer (score 0):

The 2 is a constant value (independent of frequency, dc).